# Django - ModelSerializer with model_set

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I have 2 Models, one is an Order Header, and the other is the Orden detail(s)
I want to retrieve a JSON that has the Order Header and it's details inside.
I have seen the "`model__set`" function that retrieves all header's related foreign details, but I have no idea how to make a JSON like above structure.

My models.py

```
class OrderHeader(models.Model):
    order_doc = models.CharField(...)
    client = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    header = models.ForeignKey(OrderHeader)
    var1 = models.CharField(...)
    var2 = models.CharField(...)
```

I need to receive something like:

```
[
    {
    order_doc:'1234',
    client:'Client Name',
    details:[
        {
            var1:'var1',
            var2:'var2'
        },
        {
            var1:'var01',
            var2:'var02'
        }
    ]
    },
    ...
]
```

**How can I write a serializer or a query that `json.dumps` this?**

Answer (score 1):

take a look at using [natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#natural-keys). You can define your `OrderHeader` as:

```
class OrderHeader(models.Model):
    order_doc = models.CharField(...)
    client = models.CharField(...)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.order_doc
```

and in your queryset, you can do something like this:

```
result = serializers.serialize("json", OrderDetail.objects.filter(header__id = pk), indent=2, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```

More details in the documentation

Comment: but with a natural_key I can get ONLY the values specified in the `def natural_key(self):` in one field (in this case the `header` field right? I need to get all Header fields AND all detail fields but making all the header's details an array inside the header.

Comment: the answer you gave will return something like:
[{header:'1234', var1:'var1', var2:'var2'}, {header:'1234', var1:'var1', var02:'var02'},...].
Am I wrong?

Comment: actually i haven't tested it thoroughly. Let me get back to you after looking at it